# kubectl exec into container of a multi container pod

Tags: kubernetes

I have problem login into one container of a multi-container pod.
I get the container id from the `kubectl describe pod <pod-name>`

```
kubectl describe pod ipengine-net-benchmark-488656591-gjrpc -c <container id>
```

When i try:

```
kubectl exec -ti ipengine-net-benchmark-488656591-gjrpc -c 70761432854f /bin/bash
```

It says: Error from server: container 70761432854f is not valid for pod ipengine-net-benchmark-488656591-gjrpc

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Ah once more detailed reading the man page of kubectl exec :

Flags:

```
  -c, --container="": Container name. If omitted, the first container in the pod will be chosen
  -p, --pod="": Pod name
  -i, --stdin[=false]: Pass stdin to the container
  -t, --tty[=false]: Stdin is a TTY
```

So i just used the container name from my manifest.yaml and it worked like charm.

`Name of the container: ipengine-net-benchmark-iperf-server`

```
kubectl exec -ti ipengine-net-benchmark-488656591-gjrpc -c ipengine-net-benchmark-iperf-server /bin/bash
```